# Message for dual steering vehicle

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm wondering if a common message type exists to control dual steering vehicles (both front and rear ackermann steering). I'm looking for something like Twist or Ackermann_msg.

If not, should we create a new package to hold it or is there an existing package we should add it to ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279296/message-for-dual-steering-vehicle/) by [lelongg](https://answers.ros.org/users/33223/lelongg/) on ROS Answers with karma: 50 on 2018-01-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is already the four_wheel_steering msg that can be used

https://github.com/ros-drivers/four_wheel_steering_msgs/blob/master/msg/FourWheelSteering.msg

---

Originally posted by [Vincent R](https://answers.ros.org/users/85/vincent-r/) with karma: 365 on 2018-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0